# Custom Spark partitioner for an RDD of S3 paths

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, rdd, partitioner

I have an `RDD[(Long, String)]` of S3 paths (bucket + key) with their sizes. I want to partition it in such a way that each partition gets paths whose sizes sum up approximately to the same value. That way when I read content for these paths, each partition should have the approximately the same amount of data to work on. I wrote this custom partitioner for that.

```
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

class S3Partitioner(partitions: Int, val totalSize: Long) extends Partitioner {
  require(partitions >= 0, s"Number of partitions ($partitions) cannot be negative.")
  require(totalSize >= 0, s"Number of totalSize ($totalSize) cannot be negative.")

  val pq = PriorityQueue[(Int, Long)]()
  (0 until partitions).foreach { partition =>
    pq.enqueue((partition, totalSize / partitions))
  }

  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
    case k: Long =>
      val (partition, capacityLeft) = pq.dequeue
      pq.enqueue((partition, capacityLeft - k))
      partition
    case _ => 0
  }

  def numPartitions: Int = partitions

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case p: S3Partitioner =>
      p.totalSize == totalSize && p.numPartitions == numPartitions
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode: Int = {
    (972 * numPartitions.hashCode) ^ (792 * totalSize.hashCode)
  }
}
```

The partitioner is supposed to perform best if it is fed an RDD with the keys (the sizes) sorted in descending order. When I tried to use it, I started getting this error in the code which was working before:

```
Cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue$ResizableArrayAccess
```

This is how I am using it:

```
val pathsWithSize: RDD[(Long, String)] = ...
val totalSize = pathsWithSize.map(_._1).reduce(_ + _)

new PairRDDFunctions(pathsWithSize)
  .partitionBy(new S3Partitioner(5 * sc.defaultParallelism, totalSize))
  .mapPartitions { iter =>
    iter.map { case (_, path) => readS3(path) }
  }
```

And I am not sure how to fix this. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It also looks like a waste of time. Simple `RangePartitioner` should give you a desired result, shouldn't it?

Comment: @zero323 It should? I am not sure how to use it then. Any pointers?

Comment: If you already have data in a specific order of keys and a relatively uniform distribution it should work out-of-the box.